# ng-repeat filter doesn't apply correctly

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code:

```
Titre: <input ng-model="rechercheTitre">
Organisateur: <input ng-model="rechercheOrganisateur">
....
<li ng-repeat="resultats in resultatsJSON.results | filter:rechercheTitre"> 
    <span ng-bind-html="resultats.tra_title | highlight:rechercheTitre"></span>
    Organisateur(s) : {{resultOrganisateurs}}
</li>
```

My results is correctly display but the filter in ng-repeat is applied on rechercheTitre and rechercheOrganisateur. I only want the filter applied to rechercheTitre. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution.

Correct answer is:

```
filter:{tra_type:rechercheType.tra_type}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use [object notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
ng-repeat="resultats in resultatsJSON.results | filter:{rechercheTitre: rechercheTitre}"
```

where you define by what properties (in this case `rechercheTitre`) array elements must be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I have try:

```
filter:{rechercheTitre:rechercheTitre}
```

no error in the console but when i put a letter on my rechercheTitre input, all the results are hiden.
I have also test:

```
filter:{rechercheTitre:resultats.tra_title}
```

no error in the console but in that case all the results are always displayed.

In case it help, here is how my json file is make:

```
{
  "count": 90,
  "results": [
  {
      "tra_speakers": "Jack"
      "tra_title": "test titre",
  }, ....
```